# Can I modify a specified single value in a list?

Tags: python, list, output

I need to be able to print a list where I mark desired value in the list as "*XX*", going from "XX" that is. My trouble is that I'm using a nested a list and don't know exactly how I'm supposed to locate a certain value. I also don't know if I'm able to change an integer into a string or if that would mess up the entire way the list is printed. My function to "mark" the value looks like the following:

```
  i = 0
  while i <= len(chosenseat):
    findseat = field.index(chosenseat[i])
    field[findseat] = "*"+chosenseat[i]+"*"
    for idx, row in enumerate(field):
        if idx == floor(len(field) / 2):
            print("{:^{}}".format('↓ TYST AVD ↓', (len(row) * 4) - 2))
        if idx % 2 == 1:
            row = row[::-1]
        print(("{:<4}" * len(row)).format(*row))
    i += 1
```

(I got most of the code above from Hampus Larsson here on StackOverflow!)

The program as a whole is a ticket-booking system for a train wagon and I want to be able to mark the desired seats with "**" when they've been booked. When printing the list it looks like:

```
  1   2   3   4   
  8   7   6   5   
  9   10  11  12  
   ↓ TYST AVD ↓ 
  16  15  14  13 
  17  18  19  20  
  24  23  22  21
```

Then if the user for example wants seats 19 and 20, the list should be printed as:

```
 1   2   3   4   
 8   7   6   5   
 9   10  11  12  
  ↓ TYST AVD ↓ 
 16  15  14  13  
 17  18 *19**20*  
 24  23  22  21
```

Another problem I have is that when unhooking the tickets, the "**" should be removed, but I'm currently stuck with even getting the stars in place. Is someone able to guide me in this?

Comment: Can you post how your dictionary look like?

Comment: @Crapy forgive me for asking but what is a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand what is your initial list, assuming that I did it correctly, this could be a solution :

```
import copy

seatList = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]]
chosenseat = [11, 12]

def find_in2Dlist(lst, item):
    for index, sublist in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            idx = sublist.index(item)
            return [index, idx]
        except: continue
    return None
            

def printList(mlist, chosenseat):
  i = 0
  temp = copy.deepcopy(mlist)
  while i < len(chosenseat):
      findseat = find_in2Dlist(mlist, chosenseat[i])
      if findseat == None:
          i += 1
      else:
          temp[findseat[0]][findseat[1]] = '*' + str(mlist[findseat[0]][findseat[1]]) + '*'
      i += 1
  
  for idx, row in enumerate(temp):
        if idx == len(temp) // 2:
            print("{:^{}}".format('↓ TYST AVD ↓', (len(row) * 4) - 2))
        if idx % 2 == 1:
            row = row[::-1]
        print(("{:<4}" * len(row)).format(*row))
   
def printInitialList(mlist):
    print(mList)

printList(seatList, chosenseat) #=>
# 1   2   3   4   
# 8   7   6   5   
# 9   10  11  12  
#  ↓ TYST AVD ↓ 
# 16  15  14  13  
# 17  18  *19**20*
# 24  23  22  21
```

EDIT : Because `printList` uses a copy of the initial list, this one remain unchanged and can be reused :

```
print(seatList) #=>
# 1   2   3   4   
# 8   7   6   5   
# 9   10  11  12  
#  ↓ TYST AVD ↓ 
# 16  15  14  13  
# 17  18  19  20
# 24  23  22  21
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for this, it really helped! Just a small question, let's say a seat is unbooked, how would I go about removing the "**" from the seat in the list? Can I easily add a line or two to make it be able to remove them or do I need another function altogether?

Comment: At the beginning of `printList` I copied the list : `temp = mlist.copy()` and I add the  '*' characters in `temp` instead of in the given list.  It means that the initial list remain unchanged and that you can reuse it. Does that solution  fit your needs ?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I'm trying to get it to re-print the list as soon as I remove an object from the "chosenseat" variable but it doesn't do that. As soon as I remove an object from that list, it keeps the ** there, even though, judging from the code, it should print the main list again and hence remove the ** when I'm calling it again. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah yes, we must use `deepcopy` here instead of `copy` otherwise the sublists are not copied with the top-level list. I've fixed that issue in my answer.

Comment: That did the trick! I'm forever grateful, thank you so much!